# ajax upload file response with extra data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to add a file upload option to my page.
And I use Ajax for this purpose that sends the file to the server (where it is saved)
And should get back the file name
Everything works well except that when I print what comes back instead of just getting the array I send from the server I also get extra information.
Does anyone know where this supplement comes from? and how I can get rid of it?

here is my ajax:

```
   $("#upload_file").change(function(input){
            console.log(" in upload_file");
            var file_data = $('#upload_file').prop('files')[0];
            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append('file', file_data);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>organizer/save_event_file',
                // dataType: 'text', 
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#progress_spinner').show();
                    $('body').addClass('disable_body');
                },
                success: function(response,status){
                    console.log(response);
                },
                complete: function(){
                    $('#progress_spinner').hide();
                    $('body').removeClass('disable_body');
                }
            }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("error");
            });//fail;
    });
```

this is my server function:

```
enter code here

public function save_event_file(){ // to add check and prommision
    $filePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
   //adding to the name with the current date in the end
    $date = new DateTime();
    $name = substr($_FILES['file']['name'],0,strpos($_FILES['file']['name'],'.')). '__' .$date>format('d.m.y').substr($_FILES['file']['name'],strpos($_FILES['file']['name'],'.'));
    $data = array('file' => curl_file_create($filePath, $type, $name));
    $response = $this->organizer_model->save_file($data); // save the file with the new name
    $result = array('alertcode'=>1,'response'=>$response,'name'=>$name);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

this is what I expect to be the response:

```
{"alertcode":1,"response":true,"name":"old db function__21.03.21.txt"}
```

this is the real response (The other part is the " {"alertcode":1}" in the beginning):

```
{"alertcode":1}{"alertcode":1,"response":true,"name":"old db function__21.03.21.txt"}
```

I have no problem cutting this information and then making a parse as follows:

```
var ans = JSON.parse(response.substring(response.indexOf('{"alertcode',10),response.length));
```

But I want to understand where this is coming from - in case this addition changes - and then it will cut the string badly.

Comment: Well, there is obviously additional output. You make a call to `$this->organizer_model->save_file`, does that function have any output?

Comment: no .. this is not this - I already checked this

Comment: How is `save_event_file` evoked? Is there any output in the code that triggers it?

Comment: Is `$date>format('d.m.y')` a typo?  Do you see anything in your browser dev tools - is your POST happening more than once?  It is fired on `change`, is that working as expected?